# Targeting old java release with maven+netbeans without installing the old java release?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, javac, java-6

I want errors popping up in Netbeans and during compilation when using newer features like java.nio.file.* that are not existing in Java 6 yet. Just specifying the source and target versions in the maven compiler plugin configuration does not work: maven compiles the sources and netbeans does not care about using non-Java-6 stuff.

Comment: You **can't** use features not present in Java 6 by compiling on a newer Java release and targeting the older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different things affected by setting the source version when compiling with Java 7 and/or 8. Whether or not you install Java 6, setting the source level to 6 will prevent you from using features like try with resources, multi-catch, or lambda expressions. However, this alone will not prevent you from using *APIs* defined in the newer releases.

To get the latter, you need to also specify the boot classpath. An example of this is shown in the following code.

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/pom.xml#L114-L115

In the example, the use of the boot classpath is restricted to compilations done with the `sonatype-oss-release`, which only *requires* the machine to have the older JRE (not necessarily JDK) installed only for release builds. This setting makes it easier for new users to contribute, although it means I always have to double check pull requests using the release build before merging them. I believe the balance has been successful for the long-term maintainability of the project.

Keep in mind OSX installs Java 6 using a different location and even a different file name than what Linux and Windows use, which explains why the path is parameterized the way you see in the example.

Comment: Running the code on Java 6 will prevent you from using APIs not defined in Java 6. For example, nothing in [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) including [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) will work in 6 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems the only possibility is to force using jdk 6. Configuring the bootclasspath requires a localized pom.xml pointing to a machine-specific directory which is worse.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-versions</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireJavaVersion>
                                <version>(,1.7)</version>
                            </requireJavaVersion>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```